# How to Visualize the Safety_Lidar/Depth camera data on RViz from Docker Container

Tags: rviz, mobile-robot, ros-noetic, docker

I am currently collaborating with a mobile robot, as depicted in Image 1.
[image]

The robot is equipped with two sick_safety scanners, positioned at the front and rear. The data nodes/topics are publishing from a Docker container. To access the robot's PC, I utilize SSH by entering 'ssh username@ip.' Once inside the container, I can see the topic, and echoing the topic displays the raw text data.

I attempted two different approaches to visualize the data on rviz:

Approach 1: I opened rviz from within the container, enabling me to view the rostopic list. However, upon attempting to open rviz, an error message appeared: 'qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0' (refer to Image 2).
[image]

Approach 2: I configured the IP addresses of both the robot PC and my PC. The robot was connected to a wifi-router via LAN, while my PC was connected via Wi-Fi on the same network (refer to Image 3).
[image]

Although I could see all the topics on my PC, running rviz did not display any data; there was no TF data, and the Fixed Frame option was not available (refer to Image 4).
[image]

Looking ahead, if I plan to integrate a RealSense camera with the robot, how can I visualize the camera data on rviz, whether on the robot's pc (GUI Tool) or my PC's?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics StackExchange!
Can you reformat your question to have your console output/errors in text in the question? Text in screenshots are not searchable.

Answer (score 0):

To run RViz locally on your robot but view on your PC, you will need to tunnel the XWindows connection or use a remote desktop application. However, I would not recommend this, since you shouldn't be loading your robot system with all the CPU cycles needed to run RViz.

Since you can see the topic list, you should take the next step and run a `rostopic echo /scan` (or other topic name) to verify that you are receiving data.

In your RViz screenshot it looks like you are not displaying data because RViz does not know what frame to use as its fixed frame. Typically this defaults to "/map", but you can use any frame. You probably have a "/base_link" frame, which would show you everything from the robot's perspective.

Comment: As I mentioned, I can echo the topic for example. `rostopic echo  /front/sick_safetyscanners/scan`   and I can see the text raw data. So, that means my pc is receiving the data. But I can't see the data on rviz. How I can use any frame(for example /base_link) ? There is no available frame in rviz.

Comment: In RViz, in the "Displays" panel on the left, there is a drop-down for "Global Options". Under this is an option listed as "Fixed Frame". The default value is "map", but you should either type in the fixed frame you want to use for RViz or use the drop-down to select one of the available frames.

An which frame should you use as the fixed frame? That's up to you since it depends on you specific robot and the task you are trying to visualize, so try out a few to see what works best.

Comment: There is no available in the "Fixed Frame", only default one "map". I changed it and typed "/base_link", but still I can not see anything in the Pointcloud/2. Is there any way to see which frame data is published?

Comment: You might need to debug your TF tree, then: <http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Debugging%20tools>

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But still, I have the same problem. Could't make the solution. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Since you can echo the laser topics on your PC, this would be purely an RViz configuration problem. RViz needs to know a reference frame to use for displaying the data. If you `grep` for the frame ID in your laser scan topic (`rostopic echo /front/sick_safetyscanners/scan | grep frame_id`, you should find the frame for the laser data. You can put this frame into the fixed frame to start.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I tried that things but still I can not see any frame in my pc from robot pc. I uploaded the terminal log, here you can see [link](https://amksavonia-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/md_sajib_pramanic_edu_savonia_fi/EYumm4jJkFlOv9diguclx0wBUDYZeL8nAOi2Bs1Z6kGjyw?e=IVELea)

Comment: That is odd. What happens if you `rostopic echo /tf` on both systems? That output should be the same. I'm also perplexed that you're only seeing one frame when you are in the docker container. Lastly, I just noticed that your master IP address is in the address typically used by the router, but I don't think this is causing your problem, just maybe confusing.

Comment: I ran the `rostopic echo /tf` on both system. Robot pc showing the data but my pc has no output. Here is the terminal log [Terminal Log 1](https://amksavonia-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/md_sajib_pramanic_edu_savonia_fi/EV5tTrf0H_5HuOlZUyKIb_ABC7FHTVRlSMu4ROKVCQGdHg?e=ssZ3Fp) . There you will also see the `/etc/hosts` log for both pc. Here is the [Terminal log 2](https://amksavonia-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/md_sajib_pramanic_edu_savonia_fi/EbVg3qICdSpBsKhjrq0Q4eIBPGFvWZ31f0lygHHlNR1MtA?e=nUuxSB) from `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: I find it very strange that your system is able to echo the "/scan" topic but not "/tf". I think you have the `/etc/hosts` file a little wrong on your "sajib" system (127.0.1.1 should point to "sajib"), but I don't think that should affect anything since you're referring to the computers via IP address. If you run something only on "sajib" does /tf get published?